# get the full path of web service's methods from wsdl file

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I am working with suds library -python 2.7- and I would like to get the full path of all methods from a wsdl file.
I used this code to get the list of methods from a wsdl file :

```
from suds.client import Client

url = "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL"
client = Client(url)
list_of_methods = [method for method in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods]
```

and I get something like this :

```
[GetCurrencyCodeByCurrencyName, GetCurrencyByCountry, GetCurrencyCode, GetCountries, GetCurrencies, GetISOCountryCodeByCountyName, GetISD, GetCountryByCurrencyCode, GetGMTbyCountry, GetCountryByCountryCode]
```

But I want to get something like this :

```
[http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCountryByCountryCode, ...]
```

so, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a `qname` attribute of a port?

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL"

client = Client(url)
port = client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0]
list_of_methods = [port.qname[1] + '/' + method for method in port.methods]
print(list_of_methods)
```